# Why can't I set object derived from ObservableCollection<Proddata> equal to object returned as ObservableCollection<Proddata>?

Tags: c#, observablecollection, crud, casting

I get a compile error, "Cannot implicitly conver type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection to ProddataRecsObservable'. An explicit conversion exists" See comments in following code segments.

```
//I created a custom class called ProddataRecsObservable derived from
//ObservableCollection<Proddata> so I can do some special CRUD operations for my production
//data records.

public class ProddataRecsObservable : ObservableCollection<Proddata>
{

}        

//I have another class which maps an object to a reader and the function MappAll returns an 
//Observable collection of type <T>.

public abstract class MapperBase<T>
{
    protected abstract T Map(IDataRecord record);

    public ObservableCollection<T> Mapall(IDataReader reader)
    {
        ObservableCollection<T> collection = new ObservableCollection<T>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                collection.Add(Map(reader));
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return collection;
    }
}

//I have another class derived from MapperBase called ProddataMapper.

public class ProddataMapper : WTS.Data.Mapper.MapperBase<Proddata>
{
    protected override Proddata Map(System.Data.IDataRecord record)
    {
        Proddata p = new Proddata();    

        p.PSTAT = (DBNull.Value == record["PSTAT"]) ? "" : record["PSTAT"].ToString();

 return p;
    }
}

//In my calling code, I attempt to set a ProddataRecsObservable variable equal to the 
//result of MapAll() from my ProddataMapper class but get the compile error. The error even 
//tells me they are the same type which is strange. How can I get around this?

//Calling Code:

ProddataMapper prodMapper = new ProddataMapper(); 
ProddataRecsObservable recs = prodMapper.Mapall(ProddataReader); //ERROR'S HERE <-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<Proddata>` cannot be upcasted to `ProddataRecsObservable`, there is additional logic in `ProddataRecsObservable` that `ObservableCollection<Prodddata>` doesn't know about.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see that it tells you the types are the same at all. `ProddataRecsObservable` isn't the same thing as `ObservableCollection<Proddata>` - what makes you think they're the same type? The first type derives from the second type - that doesn't make them the *same* type.

Every instance of `ProddataRecsObservable` is an instance of `ObservableCollection<Proddata>` due to the inheritance relationship, but the reverse isn't true.

What's you're doing is the equivalent of:

```
class Test : object {}

object Foo()
{
    return new object();
}
...
Test t = Foo();
```

Would you expect that to work? If so, why would you expect it to work? How is the compiler meant to know that `Foo` will *actually* return an instance of `Test` (which in fact it doesn't here - nor does your method return an instance of your derived class)? If you *wouldn't* expect that to work, why would you expect your example code to work?

Comment: +1 for drive to why by returned to the basics. Don't give me a fish teach me how to fish

Answer (score 0):

Make MapAll() abstract in the base class, and then in the ProdDataMapper provide the override:

```
public override ProddataRecsObservable Mapall(IDataReader reader)
{
   // do the downcast explicitly
    return (ProddataRecsObservable) base.MapAll(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

John Skeet is right. Try explicitly casting the result to ProddataRecsObservable in the assignment where you get the error.